# How to increment Hadoop counters in Jython UDFs in Pig

Tags: hadoop, jython, apache-pig

I would like to monitor progress of my Pig jobs.  Most of the work is done in UDFs written in Jython.  Is there a way to define/increment a Hadoop counter from within a Jython UDF?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't check it right now (sorry for untested code), 
but in Java UDFs(which are quite similar) with Pig 0.8 
it should go like this:

```
public class INC_COUNTER extends EvalFunc<DataBag> {

    @Override
    public DataBag exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {

        PigStatusReporter reporter = PigStatusReporter.getInstance();
        if (reporter != null) {
           reporter.getCounter(Counters.EXAMPLE).increment(1);//Counters.EXAMPLE is an enum value
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I hope this works and you can transform this code into the solution for Jython UDF.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a counter to your Hadoop configuration using `setInt("<counter>", <value>)`. Then everytime the UDF runs call and increment the value using `setInt("<counter>", getInt("<counter>") + 1)`. I did something similar once in a Hive UDF I think.

In the Java [docs](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration.html#setInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29).

Comment: My UDFs are written in Jython, how can I get the right instance of Hadoop configuration from within a regular Jython function?